# XAML Windows Store App - Ignore Slider.ValueChanged during drag

Tags: windows-8, slider, windows-store-apps

The default behavior for the Slider.ValueChanged event is to trigger ValueChanged multiple times as the user drags the control. Is there a way to only trigger this event when the drag is over?

One thing I already tried was binding to the Thumb.DragStarted and Thumb.DragCompleted events, and adding some flags to control the process, but these events aren't fired if the user clicks in the body of the slider, outside the thumb.

Comment: I think better solution would be to throttle ValueChanged events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to customize the control you can handle the `KeyUp` event and the `PointerCaptureLost` events instead of handling the `ValueChanged` event.

```
private void slider_PointerCaptureLost(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HandleSliderValueChange();
}

private void slider_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Make sure an arrow key, Home, or End was pressed
    //either explicitly perform the flag checks
    //if(e.Key.HasFlag(VirtualKey.Up & VirtualKey.Down & VirtualKey.Left & VirtualKey.Right & VirtualKey.Home & VirtualKey.End))

    //or check the int values
    int keyVal = (int)e.Key;
    if(keyVal >= 35 && keyVal <= 40)
       HandleSliderValueChange();
}

private void HandleSliderValueChange()
{
    //your value changed code
}
```

This should call the `HandleSliderValueChange` method when the user finishes dragging, clicks on the slider itself, or uses the arrow, Home, or End keys to change the value.